# How to fix: Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, primary-key

My code works. After I copy about 10 tables I get an error. `Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.` Okay, I know I need to generate a primary key. But why can I copy 10 or so tables over, and THEN I get the error. Does each row have to return a primary key? If a row doesn't have a primary key, how do I generate one?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LCR_ShepherdStaffupdater_1._0
{
    public class DatabaseHandling
    {
        static DataTable datatableB = new DataTable();
        static DataTable datatableA = new DataTable();
        public static DataSet datasetA = new DataSet();
        public static DataSet datasetB = new DataSet();
        static OleDbDataAdapter adapterA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        static OleDbDataAdapter adapterB = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        static string connectionstringA = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Settings.getfilelocationA();
        static string connectionstringB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Settings.getfilelocationB();
        static OleDbConnection dataconnectionB = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringB);
        static OleDbConnection dataconnectionA = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringA);
        static DataTable tableListA;
        static DataTable tableListB;

        static public void addTableA(string table, bool addtoDataSet)
        {
            dataconnectionA.Open();
            datatableA = new DataTable(table);
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand commandselectA = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]", dataconnectionA);
                adapterA.SelectCommand = commandselectA;
                adapterA.Fill(datatableA);
            }
            catch
            {
                Logging.updateLog("Error: Tried to get " + table + " from DataSetA. Table doesn't exist!", true, false, false);
            }

            if (addtoDataSet == true)
            {
                datasetA.Tables.Add(datatableA);
                Logging.updateLog("Added DataTableA: " + datatableA.TableName.ToString() + " Successfully!", false, false, false);
            }

            dataconnectionA.Close();
        }

        static public void addTableB(string table, bool addtoDataSet)
        {
            dataconnectionB.Open();
            datatableB = new DataTable(table);

            try
            {
                OleDbCommand commandselectB = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + table + "]", dataconnectionB);
                adapterB.SelectCommand = commandselectB;
                adapterB.Fill(datatableB);
            }
            catch
            {
                Logging.updateLog("Error: Tried to get " + table + " from DataSetB. Table doesn't exist!", true, false, false);
            }



            if (addtoDataSet == true)
            {
                datasetB.Tables.Add(datatableB);
                Logging.updateLog("Added DataTableB: " + datatableB.TableName.ToString() + " Successfully!", false, false, false);
            }

            dataconnectionB.Close();
        }

        static public string[] getTablesA(string connectionString)
        {
            dataconnectionA.Open();
            tableListA = dataconnectionA.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            string[] stringTableListA = new string[tableListA.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < tableListA.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringTableListA[i] = tableListA.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            }
            dataconnectionA.Close();
            return stringTableListA;
        }

        static public string[] getTablesB(string connectionString)
        {
            dataconnectionB.Open();
            tableListB = dataconnectionB.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            string[] stringTableListB = new string[tableListB.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < tableListB.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stringTableListB[i] = tableListB.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            }
            dataconnectionB.Close();
            return stringTableListB;
        }

        static public void createDataSet()
        {

            string[] tempA = getTablesA(connectionstringA);
            string[] tempB = getTablesB(connectionstringB);
            int percentage = 0;
            int maximum = (tempA.Length + tempB.Length);

            Logging.updateNotice("Loading Tables...");
            Logging.updateLog("Started Loading File A", false, false, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempA.Length ; i++)
            {
                if (!datasetA.Tables.Contains(tempA[i]))
                {
                    addTableA(tempA[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
                else
                {
                    datasetA.Tables.Remove(tempA[i]);
                    addTableA(tempA[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
            }
            Logging.updateLog("Finished loading File A", false, false, true);
            Logging.updateLog("Started loading File B", false, false, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempB.Length ; i++)
            {
                if (!datasetB.Tables.Contains(tempB[i]))
                {
                    addTableB(tempB[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
                else
                {
                    datasetB.Tables.Remove(tempB[i]);
                    addTableB(tempB[i], true);
                    percentage++;
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                }
            }
            Logging.updateLog("Finished loading File B", false, false, true);
            Logging.updateLog("Both files loaded into memory successfully", false, true, false);


        }

        static public DataTable getDataTableA()
        {
            datatableA = datasetA.Tables[Settings.textA];

            return datatableA;
        }
        static public DataTable getDataTableB()
        {
            datatableB = datasetB.Tables[Settings.textB];
            return datatableB;
        }

        static public DataSet getDataSetA()
        {
            return datasetA;
        }

        static public DataSet getDataSetB()
        {
            return datasetB;
        }

        static public void InitiateCopyProcessA()
        {
            DataSet tablesA;
            tablesA = DatabaseHandling.getDataSetA();
            int percentage = 0;
            int maximum = (tablesA.Tables.Count);

                foreach (DataTable table in tablesA.Tables)
                {
                    Logging.loadStatus(percentage, maximum);
                    OverwriteTable(table, table.TableName);
                    Logging.updateLog("Copied " + table.TableName + " successfully.", false, true, false);
                    percentage++;
                }

        }

        static void OverwriteTable(DataTable sourceTable, string tableName)
        {
            using (var destConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstringA))
            using (var destCmd = new OleDbCommand(tableName, destConn) { CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect })
            using (var destDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(destCmd))

            {
                // Since we're using a single table, we can have the CommandBuilder
                // generate the appropriate INSERT and DELETE SQL statements
                using (var destCmdB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(destDA))
                {
                    destCmdB.QuotePrefix = "["; // quote reserved column names
                    destCmdB.QuoteSuffix = "]";
                    destDA.DeleteCommand = destCmdB.GetDeleteCommand();
                    destDA.InsertCommand = destCmdB.GetInsertCommand();

                    // Get rows from destination, and delete them
                    var destTable = new DataTable();
                    destDA.Fill(destTable);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in destTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                    }

                     destDA.Update(destTable);

                    // Set rows from source as Added, so the DataAdapter will insert them
                    foreach (DataRow dr in sourceTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr.SetAdded();
                    }
                    destDA.Update(sourceTable);
                }
            }
        }



        }          
    }
```

Google was not very helpful to me on this. Please provide a coding example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No coding example is really going to work.  You have to make a determination from the table as to what is the unique identifier for the table.  If there is no primary key (or at the least, a unique index), then you are out of luck.

The only way around this is to create a dynamic command yourself, which compares every value in the table to the record you want to delete.  If they are the same, then delete them.

However, you run the risk of deleting multiple rows from the table, since there might be multiple rows in the table with the same values.