# VB.net: DELETE all rows in datagrid using MS Access

Tags: vb.net

`Sub DeleteRecords()`

```
Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM Attendance"
Dim daTestTbl As New OleDbDataAdapter(qry, con1)
Dim cbTestTbl As New OleDbCommandBuilder(daTestTbl)
Dim dtTestTbl As New DataTable("Attendance")

Try
    daTestTbl.Fill(dtTestTbl)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dtTestTbl.Rows
        dr.Delete()
    Next

    daTestTbl.Update(dtTestTbl)
    dtTestTbl.Dispose()
    daTestTbl.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)

End Try
```

An error always pops up when running the program. May I have some help?

This is the error

> `Dynamic SQL Generation for the delete command is not supported against a Select Command that thus not return any key column information.`

Comment: There are no records in your table? By the way, using "delete from attendance" is more effective in access.

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769011/sql-delete-statement-syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522710/how-to-fix-dynamic-sql-generation-for-the-deletecommand-is-not-supported-agains)